Convex hexagon $|AB|=|AF|=|AD|=|BE|=|CF|=a$, Prove $a$ reaches maximum when six points are on an ellipse.
$ABCDEF$ is a convex hexagon with constraints:$$|AB|=|AF|=|AD|=|BE|=|CF|=a\\|BC|=|EF|=|CD|=|DE|=1$$I try to prove that $a$ reaches maximum, when there exists an ellipse through the six points.
My attempt:
Suppose the points have coordinates $A(x_1,0),B(x_2,y_2),C(x_3,y_3),D(-x_1,0),E(x_3,-y_3)$
To get the numerical coordinates, in Mathematica:
points={{x1,0},{x2,y2},{x3,y3},{-x1,0},{x3,-y3},{x2,-y2}};
matrix=Table[{points[[i,1]]^2,points[[i,1]]*points[[i,2]],points[[i,2]]^2,points[[i,1]],points[[i,2]],1},{i,1,6}];
det=Det[matrix];
NSolve[{(points[[1]]-points[[2]]).(points[[1]]-points[[2]])==a^2,(points[[1]]-points[[6]]).(points[[1]]-points[[6]])==a^2,(points[[1]]-points[[4]]).(points[[1]]-points[[4]])==a^2,(points[[2]]-points[[5]]).(points[[2]]-points[[5]])==a^2,(points[[3]]-points[[6]]).(points[[3]]-points[[6]])==a^2,(points[[2]]-points[[3]]).(points[[2]]-points[[3]])==1,(points[[5]]-points[[6]]).(points[[5]]-points[[6]])==1,(points[[3]]-points[[4]]).(points[[3]]-points[[4]])==1,(points[[4]]-points[[5]]).(points[[4]]-points[[5]])==1,x1<x2<x3<-x1,y2>0,y3>0}/.a->Sqrt[(26Sqrt[13]+97)/23],{x1,x2,x2,y2,x3,y3},Reals]

This value $a=\sqrt{\frac{26 \sqrt{13}+97}{23}}\approx2.8798$ will make det vanish, so that there exists an ellipse through the six points.
The output is
$x_1 = -1.4399, x_2= 0.77061, y_2 = 1.84577, x_3 = 1.28435, y_3 = 0.987828$
To plot the hexagon and ellipse using these coordinates:
sol={x1->-1.4398985968299483`,x2->0.770610342893042`,y2->1.845774120529423`,x3->1.2843505714884054`,y3->0.9878283311448127`};
Show[Show[RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[Chop[NullSpace[matrix/. sol]][[1]].{x^2,x y,y^2,x,y,1}==0,{x,y}]],Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick],LightPink,Polygon[points/.sol],Red,Text["A",points[[1]]/.sol,{-2,0}],Text["B",points[[2]]/.sol,{1,-1}],Text["C",points[[3]]/.sol,{1,-1}],Text["D",points[[4]]/.sol,{1,-1}],Text["E",points[[5]]/.sol,{1,-1}],Text["F",points[[6]]/.sol,{1,-1}]}]],AspectRatio->Automatic]


How to prove that $a$ reaches maximum when six points are on an ellipse?
For $a>\sqrt{\frac{26 \sqrt{13}+97}{23}}\approx2.8798$, the system of equations will have no real solutions.

However, the above assumed that $B,F$ are symmetric with respect to $AD$, and $C,E$ are symmetric with respect to $AD$ which implies three diagonals $AD,BE,CF$ are concurrent, but theses assumptions are not included in the problem statement, so it is not convincing.

This seems to be related to the realization of $K_{3,3}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is infinitesimally rigid unless its six vertices lie on a conic (Theorem 14 in the article in the link in this answer). I don't know if there is a connection between this problem of maximizing $a$ and the failure of infinitesimal rigidity of the graph.

Let us see first how to realize a constellation of points as the given one.

We denote by $x$ the angles formed by $AC$ with each of $AB,AD$,
and by $X$ the length of the segment $AC$.
We denote by $y$ the angles formed by $AE$ with each of $AF,AD$,
and by $Y$ the length of the segment $AE$.

In a picture:

We assume $0^\circ<x+y<90^\circ$, else the picture moves to "the other side".
We try to see how can it be possible to realize such a situation.
The cosine theorem (generalized Pythagoras) gives us for the triangles with a vertex in $A$ and angles respectively $x$, $y$, $x+2y$, $y+2x$ the relations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
a^2+X^2 -2aX\cos x &= 1\ ,\\
a^2+Y^2 -2aY\cos y &= 1\ ,\\[2mm]
a^2+X^2-2aX\cos(x+2y) &= a^2\ , &\text{ i.e. }X&=2a\cos(x+2y)\ ,\\
a^2+Y^2-2aY\cos(y+2x) &= a^2\ , &\text{ i.e. }Y&=2a\cos(y+2x)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The last two relations could be obtained simpler from the two isosceles triangles, but for the sake of uniformity we also used the law of cosines.
We plug in the two values for $X,Y$ (in terms of $a;x,y$) into the first two equations to obtain:
$$
\begin{aligned}
a^2+4a^2\cos^2(x+2y) - 4a^2\cos x\cos(x+2y) &= 1\ ,\\
a^2+4a^2\cos^2(y+2x) - 4a^2\cos y\cos(y+2x) &= 1\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We write $\cos(x+2y)-\cos x=\cos((x+y)+y)-\cos((x+y)-y)=-2\sin y\sin(x+y)$, and the same with $x,y$ switched over to obtain:
$$
\begin{aligned}
1 - 8\sin y\sin(x+y)\cos(x+2y) &= \frac 1{a^2}\ ,\\
1 - 8\sin x\sin(x+y)\cos(y+2x) &= \frac 1{a^2}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The maximal case (and a neighborhood) has $\sin(x+y)\ne 0$, so we are interested to solve first:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin y\cos(x+2y) &= \sin x\cos(y+2x)\ , &&\text{i.e.}\\
\sin (x+3y)-\sin(x+y) &= \sin(y+3x) -\sin(x+y)\ ,&&\text{i.e.}\\
\sin (x+3y)- \sin(y+3x)&= 0 \ ,&&\text{i.e.}\\
2\sin(x-y)\cos(2x+2y)&=0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The first case reduces to $x=y$, the second case to $2(x+y)=90^\circ$.

In the  first case, which is $x=y$ and $X=Y$ and the figure is symmetric w.r.t. $AD$ as in the OP simulation, the expression to be maximized is $a$, so we equivalently minimize $1/a^2$, which is
$$
1-8\sin x\sin 2x\cos 3x
=2\cos 6x-2\cos 4x-2\cos 2x+3\ ,
$$
which after differentiation leads to the equation
$$
\begin{aligned}
0 &= 3\sin 6x -2\sin 4x -\sin 2x\ ,&&\text{i.e.}\\
0 &=\sin 2x\Big(\ 3(4\cos^2 2x-1) - 4\cos 2x -1 \Big)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and the equation in $U=\cos 2x$ is $0=3U^2-U-1$, which leads to the positive root $\displaystyle\bbox[yellow]{\ U_\pm=\frac 16(1\pm\sqrt{13})\ }$. Below, $U$ will take only the positive value.
Let $a_*$ be the relative extremal value obtained by using $U=U_+$
for the corresponding angle $x$ with $\cos 2x=U_+$.
We compute the value of $1/a_*^2$ as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac 1{a_*^2}
\min \frac 1{a^2}
&=1-8\sin x\sin 2x\cos 3x\\
&=2\cos 6x-2\cos 4x-2\cos 2x+3
\\
&=2U_+(4U_+^2-3)-2(2U_+^2-1)-2U_+ +3=\frac 19(41-52U_+)
\\
&=
\frac 1{27}(97-26\sqrt{13})\ ,
\\[2mm]
a_*^2 &= \frac {27}{97-26\sqrt{13}}
=\frac 1{23}(97+26\sqrt {13})
\\[2mm]
a_* &= \frac 1{\sqrt{23}}\sqrt{97+26\sqrt {13}}\approx
2.8797971936599053\dots\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
which corresponds to the OP maximal value of $a$.
In this second i have no rigidity argument for the fact that we are with six points on an ellipse. If this is an important issue, i will search for it.

In the second case, which is $x+y=45^\circ$ has a $90^\circ$-angle
$\widehat{BAF}$, with a picture of the following shape

the expression to be maximized is again $a$, so we equivalently minimize $1/a^2$, which is
$$
1-8\sin(45^\circ-x)\sin 45^\circ\sin x
=1-4\sqrt 2\sin(45^\circ-2x)\sin x
=3-2\sqrt 2\cos(45^\circ-2x)
\\
\ge 3-2\sqrt 2=(\sqrt2-1)^2=\frac 1{(\sqrt 2 +1)^2}\ ,
$$
and the further analysis of the relative extremal value $\sqrt 2+1$ is left to the reader.

